# Inserting issue into the database via java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a bit of a problem with inserting some data in the database. The data is being read by an CSV parser and changed to data besides that, I continue to get this error message:

```
Connected to the PostgreSQL server successfully.
Naam van de garage: P_Erasmusbrug, Longditude: 4.482313155, Latitude: 51.91024645
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.bind(SimpleParameterList.java:65)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.setStringParameter(SimpleParameterList.java:128)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.bindString(PgPreparedStatement.java:1023)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setString(PgPreparedStatement.java:374)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setString(PgPreparedStatement.java:358)
at Database.ConnectDatabase.parser(ConnectDatabase.java:80)
at Events.CSVReader.main(CSVReader.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Thank you for your service.
Naam van de garage: P_St.Jacobsplaats, Longditude: 4.482054381, Latitude: 51.92410235
Thank you for your service.
Naam van de garage: P_Schouwburgplein, Longditude: 4.473618335, Latitude: 51.92102728
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
```

Which continues for all the other lines of data. Is there maybe a way to fix this as I don't really understand what the error message includes..
The a, b2, and c2 are variables for the ''name'' , ''londitude'' and ''latitude''.

```
package Database;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectDatabase {
private final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/Project3";
private final String user = "postgres";
private final String password = "kaas123";
private Connection conn;

public Connection connect() {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        System.out.println("Connected to the PostgreSQL server successfully.");
    } catch (SQLException exception) {
        System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
    }

    this.conn = conn;
    return conn;
}

public HashMap getGarages() {
    HashMap<String, Double> newHashMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    try {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;

        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT deelgemeente, COUNT(garagenaam) FROM garages GROUP BY deelgemeente");
        while (rs.next()) {
            String deelGemeenteNaam = rs.getString("deelgemeente");
            double garageNaamCount = rs.getDouble("COUNT");
            newHashMap.put(deelGemeenteNaam, garageNaamCount);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Got an exception!");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return newHashMap;
}

public HashMap getTheftYear(int year) {
    HashMap<String, Double> newHashMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    try {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;

        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT deelgemeente, percentagediefstal FROM autodiefstal WHERE jaar = " + year);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String deelGemeenteNaam = rs.getString("deelgemeente");
            double deelPercentage = rs.getDouble("percentagediefstal");
            newHashMap.put(deelGemeenteNaam, deelPercentage);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Got an exception!");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return newHashMap;
}

public int parser(String a, float b2, float c2) {
    int updated = 0;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try {

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO testparser(garagenaam, xpos, ypos) VALUES(" + a + "," + b2 + "," + c2 + ")";
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertSQL);

        stmt.setString(1, a);
        stmt.setFloat(2, b2);
        stmt.setFloat(3, c2);

        System.out.println("Inserted data into the database...");
        updated = stmt.executeUpdate();



    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (stmt != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
        }
        try {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Thank you for your service.");
    this.conn = conn;
    return updated;

    }
}
```

Comment: removed the incompatible mysql tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't correctly using the `?` placeholders system, replace :

```
String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO testparser(garagenaam, xpos, ypos) VALUES(" + a + "," + b2 + "," + c2 + ")";
```

with

```
String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO testparser(garagenaam, xpos, ypos) VALUES(?,?,?)";
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :D The ''???'' was all I had to change, I forgot it replaces the variables immediately with mine

Comment: I'll accept your answer in the next 9 minutes, thanks for the help =)